# ceiling decimal format in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, ceil

I want to get specified format number..
help me plz..

I made function

```
    function ceilingAbsolute(inVal, pos){

        var digits = Math.pow(10, pos);

        var num = 0;

        var patten = "[0-9]{"+pos+"}$";
        var re = new RegExp(patten, "");

        num = inVal.replace(re);

        num = num * digits;

        return num;
}



var testVal = ceilingAbsolute(255555, 3) ;
```

I have expected testVal = 255000, but got "255undefined"
..

I want to get ceiling deciaml number..

somebody help please..

Comment: Why regex here, oh why?

Comment: TypeError: Object 255555 has no method 'replace'.

Comment: You chose `3` for a `6` digit long example, I'm assuming for `ceilingAbsolute(255555, 2)` you would expect `255500`..

Comment: //elclanrs Just, I know regex. :-)

Comment: //maerics oh.. I need String type..;; thank you!!

Comment: Are you trying to truncate or round to the nearest power of 10?

Comment: See my edit for truncating instead of parsing.

Comment: Please use correct terminology: `Ceiling` means to round up.  You mean `Floor` to round down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also do:

```
function absFloor(num, pos) {
  num += '';
  var len = num.length;
  if (pos < len) {
    return num.substring(0,len-pos) + ('' + Math.pow(10, pos)).substring(1);
  }
}
```

It can be reduced to two lines, but I think the test is important:

```
function absFloor(num, pos) {
  num += '';
  return num.substring(0,num.length-pos) + ('' + Math.pow(10, pos)).substring(1);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The reason you're getting `255undefined` is that you are not passing a replacement value to the `replace` function along with the regex. Why not just do:

```
function ceilingAbsolute(inVal, pos){
    var digits = Math.pow(10, pos);
    return parseInt(inVal / digits) * digits;
}
```

Comment: If you're using `Math.pow(10, pos)` twice you may as well cache it.

Comment: WOW ..

you are very FFast!!

Comment: I edited the answer since you accepted it to truncate instead of round to the nearest power of 10, since that is what your expected output was looking to do.